# What is the difference between ISR registered via the IDT and an "IRQ line" regsitered using `request_irq()`?

Tags: linux-kernel, x86, interrupt

The kernel code suggests "IRQ vector layout" never changes, but offers a function called `request_irq()` which supposedly adds an "IRQ line". What is IRQ line in this context?

What is the difference between ISR registered via the IDT and an "IRQ line" regsitered using `request_irq()`?

Here's the openning paragraph from the IRQ vector layout setting ([irq_vectors.h](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.15/source/arch/x86/include/asm/irq_vectors.h)).

```C
/*
 * Linux IRQ vector layout.
 *
 * There are 256 IDT entries (per CPU - each entry is 8 bytes) which can
 * be defined by Linux. They are used as a jump table by the CPU when a
 * given vector is triggered - by a CPU-external, CPU-internal or
 * software-triggered event.
 *
 * Linux sets the kernel code address each entry jumps to early during
 * bootup, and never changes them. This is the general layout of the
 * IDT entries:
 *
 *  Vectors   0 ...  31 : system traps and exceptions - hardcoded events
 *  Vectors  32 ... 127 : device interrupts
 *  Vector  128         : legacy int80 syscall interface
 *  Vectors 129 ... LOCAL_TIMER_VECTOR-1
 *  Vectors LOCAL_TIMER_VECTOR ... 255 : special interrupts
 *
 * 64-bit x86 has per CPU IDT tables, 32-bit has one shared IDT table.
 *
 * This file enumerates the exact layout of them:
 */
```

Notice: **"Linux sets the kernel code address each entry jumps to early during bootup, *and never changes them."**

And here is [`request_irq()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.15/source/kernel/irq/manage.c#L2071):

```c
 /*
 *  request_threaded_irq - allocate an interrupt line
 *  @irq: Interrupt line to allocate
 *  @handler: Function to be called when the IRQ occurs.
 *        Primary handler for threaded interrupts.
 *        If handler is NULL and thread_fn != NULL
 *        the default primary handler is installed.
 *  @thread_fn: Function called from the irq handler thread
 *          If NULL, no irq thread is created
 * (.......)
 *
 *  This call allocates interrupt resources and enables the
 *  interrupt line and IRQ handling. From the point this
 *  call is made your handler function may be invoked. Since
 *  your handler function must clear any interrupt the board
 *  raises, you must take care both to initialise your hardware
 *  and to set up the interrupt handler in the right order.
 */
```

Which allegedly offers to add an IRQ handler. I guess they are refering different things, but couldn't understand what are those two different things.

It seems `request_irq()` affects `/proc/interrupts`, but this doesn't seem to be the same table mentioned in the beginning. Using `request_irq()` I could easily override exception handlers like 0 (allegedly, divide by zero exception) and 0x80 (allegedly, legacy syscall) with no effect to the system and no way to trigger them.

Comment: You are confusing the x86-specific interrupt dispatch table (IDT) with the generic interrupt layer.  The x86 table is used as a front end to map to generic interrupts. Other architectures have their own methods. The struct irq_desc is created and used dynamically.  Otherwise it would not be possible to load modules that  contain interrupt handlers. /proc/interrupts is the table of generic interrupts.

Comment: @stark Indeed, but it's `struct irq_desc` that's the front end for mapping generic interrupts to architecture-specific interrupts, not the other way around, no?

Comment: You are confused by terminology. There are devices interrupts and CPU **exceptions** (which are historically called interrupts).